# JQGrid Subgrid doesn't load if loadonce is set to true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I have a JQGrid with a subgrid (simple one, not as a grid) which worked fine till yesterday. Then I discovered the powerful flag loadonce=true which gives me pagination, search, etc. for free. But since I have enabled loadonce the subgrid stopped working and when I click on the plus to expand a row the loading box appears and doesnt go away. If I remove loadonce=true everything works as expected. Here is my javascript, thanks in advance.

```
$("#testsTable").jqGrid({
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "GetCurrentStatusServlet",
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:['Suite', 'Test Case', 'Last Update', 'Status','Actions'],
    colModel:[
              {name:'suite',index:'suite', width:50, sorttype:"int"},
              {name:'name',index:'name', width:300, formatter:nameFmatter},
              {name:'lastupdate',index:'lastupdate', width:150, formatter:"date"},
              {name:'status',index:'status', width:50, formatter: fmt_status,align:"center"},
              {name:'act',index:'act', width:100, align:"left"} 
              ],
              rowNum:150,
              width:1200,
              height:800,
              rowList:[150,300,500],
              pager: $('#pager1'),
              viewrecords: true,
              multiselect: true,
              caption: buildName,
              sortorder: "asc",
              sortname: "suite",
              subGrid: true,
              subGridUrl : "GetCurrentSubGridStatusServlet",
              subGridType: "xml",
              subGridModel: [ {
                  name:  ['Test Method', 'Last Update', 'Status'],
                  width : [250, 200, 100],
                  params: ['name']
              }],
            loadonce: true,
                  gridComplete: function(){
                      var ids = $("#testsTable").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                      for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
                          var cl = ids[i];

                          var test = new Array();
                          test.push($("#testsTable").getCell(cl, 'name'));
                          run = "<button class=\"runBtn\" onclick=\"runTests('"+test+"')\">Run</>"; 
                          log = "<button class=\"logBtn\" onclick=\";\">Log</>"; 
                          $("#testsTable").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:run+log});
                      } 
                      setupButtons();
                  }
});
$("#testsTable").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
```

Comment: If you use `subGridType:"xml"`, you should have no problem with `loadonce:true` parameter at least in the theory. Of course including `loadonce:true` follow to executing another code. If you has a live example the url could help to analyse the problem. If you post more full example which can be used to reproduce the problem I could try to help you.

Comment: any example would do. add loadonce=true there for instance http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2eb0giikm.htm

Comment: also found similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316422/jqgrid-problem-binding-subgrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging I found the your error is very easy: in your grid you use

```
subGridType: "xml"
```

instead of correct

```
subgridtype: "xml"
```

(see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#properties)). So the unknown parameter `subGridType` will be just ignored in your current grid and the value of `datatype` will be used. The value of `datatype` are changed to `local` after the first grid loading in case of the usage of `loadonce:true`.

Additionally I would recommend you use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to make 'click' binding. You current implementation is very slow if you would have many rows in the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) which described more effective way.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, second time you save my ass :)